# Why does "show flag history" show also the deleted comments?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, comment-flags, flag-history

When I click on "show flag history," I get a page that shows the flags raised for a post, together this any deleted comments. If the deleted comments are posted before the flags are raised, it's not easy to find the flags.

In which case knowing which comments have been deleted is important to understand a flag? Knowing when the post has been created can be useful (although is information available from the question page, where the "mod" link is shown), but I cannot think a case where to understand a flag is necessary to look at the deleted comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments are often deleted specifically BY flagging them. This can either be done by users if a single comment gets flagged by a few normal users it will automatically be deleted. It can also be done by moderators in a single step. Using the flag function to delete comments tags them with a reason why they were deleted. "Obsolete", "Too chatty", "Offensive" etc.

The deleted comments that are showing up under flag history are undoubtedly ones that have gotten deleted in response to flags, whether automatically or otherwise.